# AsyncCallback & Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I get the error `Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.` at the last line of the sample below..

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
myRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), Tuple.Create(myRequest, Jtype.session_get));
myRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), Tuple.Create(myRequest, Jtype.session_stats));
```

I guess it has something to do with the fact that i do not use threads for each `BeginGetRequestStream` but i am not totally sure.. Any ideas please? Why am i getting this error? How can i solve it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe you are not allowed to use the same request object to start a request when it's already started? Did you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use same `myRequest` object to initiate two async Http calls.
Use another instance of `HttpWebRequest` if you must make two async calls together.